# Какова ошибка в коде? Запись данных из полей в MySQL

Tags: php, sql

> Notice: Undefined variable: query in /var/www/user7272/data/www/world.saratov-reg.ru/engine/addnews.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/user7272/data/www/world.saratov-reg.ru/engine/addnews.php on line 17

При коде:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo "
<center>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='text' size='120' name='title' placeholder='Название:'/><br>
<textarea style='max-width: 900px;min-width: 900px;border: 0px;height:250px;' placeholder='Текст новости:' type='comment' size='50' name='text'></textarea><br>
<input type='text' size='120' name='date' placeholder='Дата создания:'/><br>
<input class='button_nohover auth_main' type='submit' size='50'/>
</form>
";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$title = 'НАЗВАНИЕ'/*$_POST['title']*/;
$date = '1 Января 2016 года'/*$_POST['date']*/;
$text = 'ОПИСАНИЕ'/*$_POST['text']*/;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "world", "yan629134CL", "server");
$mysqli->$query = "insert into wNews (title, text, date) values ($title,$text,$date)";
?>
```

Как исправить? И даже еслибы этот код работал, он бы записывал данные в таблицу?

Comment: Как "ошибка" проявляется, конечно же, не нужно писать, да?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов - Вы профессионал или Вы не профессионал? Должны только взглянув на код сразу увидеть, что в нем неправильно.

Comment: @Igor автор вопроса может оказаться без чувства юмора

Comment: @splash58: ВладимирМартьянов - без телепатических способностей, автор - без чувства юмора. Плохо дело.

Comment: @Igor даже смотреть не буду, если нет хоть сколько-то внятного описания как проблема проявляется.

Comment: Может все дело в том, что вы переменные заключаете в знак "`" ? Что неправильно. В этот значок нужно заключать имена полей, а не передаваемые значения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - Естественно, дело в бардаке с кавычками.

Comment: @Igor да не только =) там еще и значения переменных не считаются потому что все это написано в одинарных кавычках =)

Comment: @W_0rld  http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  вот тут в описании этой функции есть примеры. А значения переменных никогда прямо в текст не включайте

Comment: Проблема в том что в базу текст не добавляется, попробую ваши советы. Мой код вообще должен же отправлять запросы в базу? Это весь код, переменные берутся с формы по гет-заросу.

Comment: @W_0rld `"insert into wNews (title, text, date) values ($title,$text,$date)"` не будет работать, потому что надо `"insert into wNews (title, text, date) values ('$title','$text','$date')"` и то может не записаться, если `date` у вас в базе имеет формат `date` а не `varchar` к примеру.....и что это за бред сумасшедшего: `$mysqli->$query` ?

Comment: @W_0rld вот как должно ваше действо выглядить ...без учета плейсхолдеров конечо........... http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3aei-2bdt

Answer (score 1):

зделайте var_dump самого запроса к базе, я думаю причина в том что вы используете неправильные скобки:

```
$title = "new post";
$text = "new text";
```

все символы в одинарных кавычках (') интерпретируются как обычный текст

```
$query = 'insert into posts (title, text) values ("$title" ,"$text")';
//запрос будет иметь вид такой
//insert into posts (title, text) values ("$title" ,"$text")
```

важной особеностью двойных кавычек (") это обработка переменных:

```
$query = "insert into posts (title, text) values (\"$title\" ,\"$text\")";
//запрос будет иметь вид такой
//insert into posts (title, text) values ("new post" ,"new text")
```

p.s. это только пример работы со строками, такого рода запросы нельзя использовать на живом сервисе, так как этот код подвержен sql-инъекциям,
хорошей практикой есть использование  [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

ознакомтесь с [документацией](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Вам не помешает самому ознакомиться с [документацией](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sb97d5bb/1/ Вот мой код, пишет ошибки: Notice: Undefined variable: query in /var/www/user7272/data/www/world.saratov-reg.ru/engine/addnews.php on line 17

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/user7272/data/www/world.saratov-reg.ru/engine/addnews.php on line 17

Comment: @W_0rld не $mysqli->$query, а $mysqli->query - это во первых, а во вторых @ Ипатьев правильно говорит по поводу sql-инъекций.

Comment: @Ипатьев, мой ответ - это пример работы со СТРОКАМИ, если ты не обратил внимание

Comment: @esperant если у вас `$query` в двойных ковычках, то переменные уже можно писать в одинарных, а не двойных с экранированием

Comment: @АлексейШиманский cпасибо, я это знаю это только пример

Answer (score -1):

Почитал PDO, вот теперь все как надо:

```
<?php
$dataSource = 'mysql:dbname=server;host=localhost';
$user = 'world';
$password = '';
$db = new PDO($dataSource, $user, $password);
$db->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
$db->exec("SELECT id, title, text, date FROM wNews ORDER BY bid ASC");
$db->null;
?>
```

Comment: нет, здесь все как не надо

Comment: @W_0rld спрашивали про инсерт, написали код селект. Где логика?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский логика где-то рядом.